# Re-toggle Div after page reload

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I'm using jQuery to toggle some hidden DIVs on a blog page I've created. There are many hidden divs on the page, one for each blog post, all of the same class, and the content of each is loaded using PHP and MySQL.  Each hidden DIV contains a form - a leave comment form for the blog posts.  So initially, just the blog post is showing, then the user clicks a link which shows a form to leave a comment.  After the comment is submitted, the page is reloaded.  When the page is reloaded the DIV closes again.  I want that DIV to remain open (while all the others on the page with the same class remain closed).  Here is a fiddle illustrating what I'm talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZLkz/9/

Here is my jQuery function as it stands now:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $(".toggleCommentBox").click(function () {
             $(this).next(".showComments").toggle()
           });
        });
```

The submit button doesn't work on the fiddle, but as you can see, each hidden DIV has the same class (they're generated using a PHP while loop).  Once the submit button is pushed, the page is reloaded and I would like the DIV containing the form that was used to  be open.  All the others should be closed.

Can anyone help me out with this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:  I neglected to point out that my form processing and database updating is all done with PHP.  I'm not sure how to use AJAX to do so.  Can anyone provide code either with the AJAX method or preferably using PHP as that is my main coding language?

@SarathSprakash - Here is my PHP code.  filter() is a custom PHP function to filter out HTML and other potentially harmful input in the form fields.  The comment form includes a name field, comment field, and the date and time are automatically collected using the php date functions.  Each comment is then inserted into the database "comments" with a unique postID.  Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated!

```
     <?php 

       if(isset($_POST['submitComment'])) {

         foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
          $data[$key] = filter($value); 
         }

         $date = date('l') . ", " . date('F') . " " . date('j') . date ('S') . " at " . date('g') . ":" . date('i') . date ('a');

         $sql_insert = "INSERT into `comments` (`postID`, `comment`, `name`, `date`)
          VALUES ('$data[postID]', '$data[commentarea]', '$data[name]', '$date')";

         mysql_query($sql_insert, $adLink) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error()); 
     } 


     ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I guess this is what you need

### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="toggleCommentBox" onclick="return false;">Open 1</a>

<div class="showComments" style="display:none;">
    <form method="post" name="infoForm" action="blah.php">Form fields here
        <br />
        <input type="button" name="submitInfo" value="Submit" class='click' />
    </form>
</div>
<br>
<a href="#" class="toggleCommentBox" onclick="return false;">Open 2</a>

<div class="showComments" style="display:none;">
    <form method="post" name="infoForm" action="blah.php">Form fields here
        <br />
        <input type="button" name="submitInfo" value="Submit" class='click' />
    </form>
</div>
<br> <a href="#" class="toggleCommentBox" onclick="return false;">Open 3</a>

<div class="showComments" style="display:none;">
    <form method="post" name="infoForm" action="blah.php">Form fields here
        <br />
        <input type="button" name="submitInfo" value="Submit" class='click' />
    </form>
</div>
<br>
```

### code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".toggleCommentBox").click(function () {
         $(this).next(".showComments").toggle();

     });
     $(".click").click(function () {
         var frm = $(this).parent('form');
         $.ajax({
             url: frm.attr('action'),
             type:'POST',
             data:frm.serialize(),
             success: function (response) {
                  // do your code
             },
             error:function(xhr)
             {
                 console.log(xhr);
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

### php

```
<?php 

         foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

          if (!is_array($value))
                $data[$key] = filter_var($value);
         }
         $date = date('l') . ", " . date('F') . " " . date('j') . date ('S') . " at " . date('g') . ":" . date('i') . date ('a');

         $sql_insert = "INSERT into `comments` (`postID`, `comment`, `name`, `date`)
           VALUES ('".$data['postID']."', '".$data['commentarea']."', '".$data['name']."', '$date')"

         mysql_query($sql_insert, $adLink) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error()); 

    echo $data['postID'].",".$data['commentarea'].",".$data['name'].",".$date;
    ?>
```

Hope this helps, thank you

Comment: I've never used AJAX to process a form, I've always used PHP, though it might not be a best practice.  How can I take the form variables and update the MySQL database in the "do your code" part of your solution?

Comment: @JohnO its not on the client side, it is on the php side we update database and if there is any response we want to show or paste in your page you have to use the "do your code part". i dont see a  element with name "submitComment" in your form.

Comment: The submitInfo button on my forms in the fiddle is actually the submitComment form on my site.  I changed the names accidently when I made the fiddle!

Comment: When I use your jQuery code and press the link to open the comment box, a popup opens up showing the code for the entire page...

Comment: The comment DIV is still closed when the page reloads. I'm sure I've implemented all of your code correctly though.

Comment: @JohnO if the page reloads then you have not implemented my code, chnage your html as I have updated above

Comment: I addded the click class to the button...should I remove the action= from the form?

Comment: @JohnO you just change the type attribute to type='button' and class='.click'

Comment: Did both of those...nothing happens when I press the submit button now!

Comment: could you send your php as well as html code to cleardoubts@gmail.com

Comment: Just got it to work...was missing a semi-colon in the PHP at the end of the $sql_insert statement!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Give each blogpost a unique class and then using PHP you can insert some jQuery to open that particular post on pageload after you've processed the comment.
Alternatively you can submit the form via AJAX and therefore negate the need for a reload altogether and hence the user will be exactly where they were before the form submit.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little further how I can use jQuery to open the post after I processed it and updated the DB with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use `$(this).addClass("active");` to add class for opened form and in page load open the form that has "active" class

Comment: How do I open the form that has the active class?